# Having problems while trying to remove user generated todos using a recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Modal Layer = `ToDoListLab.java` (Singleton class), `ToDo.java`

Controller Layer = `ToDoListFragment.java`

I am trying to create a todo list application using the recycler view, on my fragment view I have an edit-text, an add and a deleted button, on my recycler row view I have a simple textview and a check-box. I have created a `ToDo.java` modal class that when the user types within the edit-text and presses the add button an object of the `ToDo.java` class is created, the text within the edit-text passes to the `ToDo.setTitle` method, that object when created passes to the Array-List present within the `ToDoListLab.java` class and then later the rows are inflated by the recycler view, now I want to remove those rows when the user check's the checkbox and then presses the deleted button but I am having problems with it, I tried to put a checkbox listener within the view-holder which would set the `mToDo.setSolved() == true` and then delete button's onclicklistener would remove those element from the array list but it's not working, only the last row was removed, what should I do?

ToDo.java

```
public class ToDo {

private String mTitle;
private boolean mSolved;

/*public ToDo(String Title, boolean Solved){

    mTitle = Title;
    mSolved = Solved;
}*/

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public boolean isSolved() {
    return mSolved;
}

public void setSolved(boolean solved) {
    mSolved = solved;
}
}
```

ToDoListLab.java

```
public class ToDoListLab {

private static ToDoListLab sToDoListLab;
private List<ToDo> mToDoList;

public static ToDoListLab get(Context context){

    if (sToDoListLab == null){

       sToDoListLab = new ToDoListLab(context);
    }
    return sToDoListLab;
}

private ToDoListLab (Context context){

    mToDoList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<ToDo> getToDo(){
    return mToDoList;
}

public void addToDo(ToDo todo){

    mToDoList.add(todo);
}

public void removeToDo(ToDo toDo){

    mToDoList.remove(toDo);
}
}
```

ToDoListFragment.java

```
public class ToDoListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mToDoListRecyclerView;
private ToDoAdapter mAdapter;
private EditText mTitleEditText;
private ToDo mToDo;
private Button mAddButton;
private Button mDeleteButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do_list, container, false);

    mTitleEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_toDo);
    mAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addButton_toDo);
    mDeleteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton_toDo);

    mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mToDo = new ToDo();
            mToDo.setTitle(mTitleEditText.getText().toString());
            ToDoListLab.get(getActivity()).addToDo(mToDo);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    /*mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mToDo.isSolved() == true){

                ToDoListLab.get(getActivity()).removeToDo(mToDo);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });*/

    mToDoListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_toDo);
    mToDoListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    updateUI();

    return view;
}

private void updateUI() {
    ToDoListLab ToDoLab = ToDoListLab.get(getActivity());
    List<ToDo> toDo = ToDoLab.getToDo();
    mAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(toDo);
    mToDoListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class ToDoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ToDo mToDo;
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;

    public ToDoHolder (View itemView){

        super(itemView);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_toDo);
        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_toDo);
        /*mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                mToDo.setSolved(isChecked);
            }
        });*/
    }

    public void bindToDo(ToDo toDo){

        mToDo = toDo;
        mTitleTextView.setText(mToDo.getTitle());
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mToDo.isSolved());

    }
}

private class ToDoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoHolder>{

    private List<ToDo> mToDos;

    public ToDoAdapter(List<ToDo> toDos){

        mToDos = toDos;
    }

    @Override
    public ToDoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_to_do, parent, false);

        return new ToDoHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ToDoHolder holder, int position) {
        ToDo toDo = mToDos.get(position);
        holder.bindToDo(toDo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mToDos.size();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other recyclerview methods like

```
notifyItemRemoved(int position)
```